# Creating a Dictionary: Assigning an Array of Ints as Keys to another array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of Arrays and an Array of Integers and want to create a dictionary with the Integers Array elements as keys to elements in the Array of Array.

I have tried a number of iteration methods without much luck. Any thoughts or ideas?

```
var populationArray = [[98, 8, 45, 34, 56], [9, 13, 65, 4, 90], [24, 5, 4, 56, 88], [3, 55, 22, 19, 10], [8, 33, 26, 93, 16], [31, 38, 92, 70, 36], [9, 39, 15, 14, 66]]

var IntegerKeys = [17, 41, 10, 34, 5, 85, 87]

var Dictionary : [Int: [Int]] = [:]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ZoffDino's answer does work, however it would crash if the `populationArray` would contain less elements than `integerKeys`. I'm proposing a method that doesn't have this flaw:

```
var populationArray = [[98, 8, 45, 34, 56], [9, 13, 65, 4, 90], [24, 5, 4, 56, 88], [3, 55, 22, 19, 10], [8, 33, 26, 93, 16], [31, 38, 92, 70, 36], [9, 39, 15, 14, 66]]

var IntegerKeys = [17, 41, 10, 34, 5, 85, 87]

var dictionary : [Int: [Int]] = [:]

for (key, value) in zip(IntegerKeys, populationArray) {
    dictionary[key] = value
}
```

Comment: Sweet. I totally did not realise that. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var populationArray = [[98, 8, 45, 34, 56], [9, 13, 65, 4, 90], [24, 5, 4, 56, 88], [3, 55, 22, 19, 10], [8, 33, 26, 93, 16], [31, 38, 92, 70, 36], [9, 39, 15, 14, 66]]

var IntegerKeys = [17, 41, 10, 34, 5, 85, 87]

var Dictionary = [Int: [Int]]()

// Swift 2.0
for (index, key) in IntegerKeys.enumerate() {
    Dictionary[key] = populationArray[index]
}

// Swift 1.2
for (index, key) in enumerate(IntegerKeys) {
    Dictionary[key] = populationArray[index]
}
```

Comment: Sweet. ;) Thanks @zoff-dino